# How to access bearer token client-side from Angular Elements component hosted within ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, bearer-token, angular-elements

I have an asp.net website which requires a login. Subsequent to successfully logging in, I can see that API calls have an Authorization request header with a bearer token. I have an Angular Elements web component on a particular page, and I need it to acquire the bearer token so that it can make authorized requests to a corresponding API. I'm assuming the bearer token is somehow stored on the client so that subsequent requests will have access to it? How do I access the bearer token and make it available to my Angular elements component? Thanks!